# Text does not fit in table - HTML

Tags: html, css

After going through many solutions non of them could solve my problem.

I have a `<td>` which has a `<table>` in it. However, the text inside this inner table does not fit in. Text clips out. I tried various things like `overflow:hidden`, `table-layout: fixed` on the `<table>` and `word-wrap:break-word` on `<td>` and still it didn't solve the problem.

**Here's my code:**

```
<table id="table1">
<tr>
    <td id="td1">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/165/232" />
    </td>
    <td id="td2">Long text goes here</td>
    <td id="td3" rowspan="7">
        <table id="table2">
            <tr>
                <td>Long text goes here</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**And here's the CSS:**

```
#table1 {
    width: 765px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-spacing: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#td1 {
    width: 175px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#td2 {
    vertical-align: top;
}
#td3 {
    width: 180px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
}
#table2 {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-spacing: 0;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

The content inside the inner table clips out. Could anyone please provide a solution so that the inner table can have proper content in it without clipping.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6s2A3/1/)

Comment: Try to avoid inline CSS; it's not a proper way to define styles for your HTML. Use a separate stylesheet instead.

Comment: you are giving an ID `#table2` to table; but in CSS you have given a space like `#table 2`.  make sure there is no space in ID name.

Comment: it appears just fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved much more simply. Let's do this with `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`. We can layout block elements with similar behaviour to a table, but much simpler and easier to maintain.

[Read more on CSS display](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

[Have a Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/aWLnj/3/)

CSS

```
.box {
    border: solid 1px #CCC;
    display: table;
    padding: 10px;
}
.box div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.right {
    border: solid 1px #F00;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
    </div>
    <div class="center">Content</div>
    <div class="right">Content</div>
</div>
```